# Can't log into phpMyAdmin for XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I know that there are other posts asking this same question but I've tried all the methods I've seen and to no avail. I can use the Apache server fine but can't log into `phpMyAdmin`, it comes up with the error:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

That's with `auth_type` set to `config` in `config.inc.php`; when I set this to `cookie` instead I get the error:

```
#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

I have tried setting the password in `config.inc.php`, I've tried using `resetroot.bat` and neither of these methods worked. I also added the line `--datadir=c:/xampp/mysql/data` to the `resetroot.bat` file, but that didn't change anything either.

Does anyone have any other ideas or should I just reinstall XAMPP?

Comment: Reinstall xampp. I did it twice or thrice before I actually got the config right, I always messed up on the security script.

Comment: Yeah, did that, working now. Will never know what had happened! Oh well, it's time to move on...